# how to display a list of data using display:table

Tags: hibernate, struts2

i have to display list of companies name  and their own contact in jsp form  like that

```
-company1 
    contact1
    contact2
-company2
    contact1
    contact2
..............
```

i don't know how to do that any suggestion  or link of examples?
PS : in DB i have table of company and contact (related by FK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using hibernate you could use your DAO in order to get the information once you have the information (i.e a `List` of companies) you can do it with ajax and json in first place you have to download json plugin for Struts2
paste this in your Maven pom file or donwload the jar file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16.3</version>
</dependency>
```

also in order to get your json objects you have to serialize all your clases

```
public class Company implements Serializable {// code getters; setters;}
```

and in your action class

```
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Action(value = "getCompanies", results = {
@Result(type = "json", name = "success")})
public class FetchCompanies extends ActionSupport {
     public List<Company> listOfCompanies = new ArrayList<Company>();

     @Override
     public String execute() {
        CompanyDAO dao = new CompanyDAO();
        listOfCompanies = dao.query("FROM Company");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    //Getter Setter
}
```

and then create an `.js` file with an ajax call to populate your table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getCompanies.action",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery.each(data.listOfCompanies, function(i, val) {
                $('#yourBody').append("<tr><td>" + val.attribute1OfYourCompanyClass + "</td></tr>");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and this is how your html could look like

```
       <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Attribute1</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="yourBody">
                    //In this section ajax call will insert your information
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        </div>
```